# How to add values that has the same id

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL, was looking around for this answer on the internet but I just don't know the specific keywords to use. I tried using sum function and distinct function but I just couldn't figure this out.

So I have a table like this

```
product_id    Sales
11            32
11            28
12            20
12            22
12            10
```

How do I group this table so that the same product_id has a total sales (adding all of the sales). I am trying to achieve the result like this:

```
product_id    Sales
11            60
12            52
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Search for `GROUP BY` and `aggregate functions`.

Comment: SELECT product_id, SUM(Sales) FROM table_name GROUP BY product_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select product_id, sum(Sales) from table
   group by product_id order by product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this should work...

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(Sales)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(Sales) AS total_sales
FROM tablename
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
```

See http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php and http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php